# How do I extract these XML elements into a List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this XML in which I am trying to get the output values of the `<Daily>` element.

```xml
<Person>
<Man>
    <Routine> 
        <Entry>
            <Daily>food</Daily>
            <Daily>drink</Daily>
            <Daily>sleep</Daily>
            <Daily>driving</Daily>
            <Daily>work</Daily>
        </Entry>
    </Routine>
</Man>
</Person>
```

C# code:

```csharp
verb = (from el in root.Elements("Entry").Descendants("Daily")
  select(string) el)
 .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (att, i) => att.Append(i), x => x.ToString());

Console.WriteLine(verb);
```

Through this C# code, I am able to get all the values in `<Daily>` individually be hovering over the `el` string while debugging.
However, `verb` displays them all together like this, without any spaces.

```csharp
"fooddrinksleepdrivingwork"
```

What changes should I make to my code to get the elements as a `List<string>` or, at least, a `string` separated by commas?

Comment: Your strings are not separated by commas or spaces because you're not separating them with commas or spaces.  Have you tried separating them with commas or spaces?  Your code produces a single `string` yet the title is asking for a `List<string>`; which do you want?

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews I am asking for List<string>; if it's possible to do by that

Comment: replace the `StringBuilder` with `List` and use `Add` instead of `Append`? though with `linq`, you can do something like `.Descendants("daily").Select(xml => xml.Value).ToList()` should produce list of string too.

Comment: If you want a single string I would use [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0) instead of `Aggregate`. If you want it in a list just delete your entire aggregate call and call [`.ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @BagusTesa You'd need to change the third `x => x.ToString()` argument as well.  Or you could entirely replace `Aggregate()` with `ToList()`, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're concatenating the elements value in one string, instead of storing them into a `List<string>`. Calling `ToList` instead of `Aggregate` would do the trick.

```
verb = (from el in root.Elements("Entry").Descendants("Daily")
  select(string) el)
  .ToList();
```

you can also do this :

```
var daily = root
                .Descendants("Entry")
                .Elements("Daily")
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .ToList();
```